# Cambiar color de boton segun campo de la BD

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola quiero cambiar el color de mis botones dependiendo del numero que este en un campo de mi base de datos, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera pero al momento de entrar a mis botones no me cambia el color, me los deja igual, tampoco me lanza una excepcion.

```
try {
        conexion cc = new conexion();

        ps = con.prepareStatement("Select det_mesa_estado from detalle_pedido where det_mesa=1");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String num=rs.getString("det_mesa_estado");

            if (num=="1") {
                jButton2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            } else if (rs.getString("det_mesa_estado")=="2") {
                jButton2.setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else if (rs.getString("det_mesa_estado") == null) {
                jButton2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto usar el método `setBackground(<Color>);` para cambiar el color del botón pero el problema aquí es la compraración de Strings-

Esto es incorrecto:

```
if (num=="1") {
```

debe ser:

```
if (num.equals("1")) {
```

Esto realizaría el cambio para un buen funcionamiento de tu código:

```
       if (num.equals("1")) {
            jButton2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        } else if (rs.getString("det_mesa_estado").equals("2")) {
            jButton2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (rs.getString("det_mesa_estado").equals(null)) {
            jButton2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        }
```

---

**En el lenguaje Java se útiliza la función [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) para comparar strings, NUNCA debería usarse el operador `==` .**